# Create and save Blobs server-side with PlayFramework 1.2.x

Tags: image, jpa, playframework, blob

I have some thousands of images that I would like to be able to insert into my database as Blobs with some Java code, to avoid spending 2 months adding them one by one.

The problem is that i have a model looking like :

```
public class Picture extends Model {
    public Blob image;
    public Date uploadDate;
    public String title;

    public Picture(Blob image, Date uploadDate, String title) {
        // usual stuff...
    }
}
```

How can I create Blobs, using some constructor or a factory ? I couldn't find anything like that yet.

Comment: Have you tried using [`new Blob().set(java.io.InputStream is, java.lang.String type)`](http://www.playframework.com/documentation/api/1.2.5/play/db/jpa/Blob.html#set%28java.io.InputStream,%20java.lang.String%29). Actually I haven't tried using method, only just looking at the source.. ;)

Comment: It seems I missed that one... not very intuitive though !
Thanks :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From the comment above, the solution simply is :

```
 Blob myBlob = new Blob().set(java.io.InputStream is, java.lang.String type)
```